# While inserting in arraydoes doing n++ increases size of array? Does it actually allocates addition contagious memory location for array?

Tags: arrays, c, memory

C Program to insert an element at a specific position in an array:

Is extra contagious memory location is actually allocated and an array with increases size formed when this code runs?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[100] = { 0 };
    int i, x, pos, n = 10;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = i + 1;
 
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    x = 50;
 
    pos = 5;
 
    // increase the size by 1
    n++;
 
    // shift elements forward
    for (i = n-1; i >= pos; i--)
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
 
    // insert x at pos
    arr[pos - 1] = x;
 
    // print the updated array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have an array size of 10 instead of 100?

Comment: TLDR (just answering to the title)... No. Once created, **arrays never ever change size**.

Comment: Yes , if array was intitially of size 10 then what would happen?

Answer (score 1):

> Is Extra Contagious Memory Location is actually allocated and an array with increases size formed when this code runs?

No, once an array is defined, like here:

```
  int arr[100] = ...
```

its size is fixed (as defined).

Comment: Then how is this inserting into array?

Comment: If array was originally of size 10 , then what will happen.Will it still be considered inserting into array?

Comment: Writing out of an array's boundaries invokes undefined behaviour. The moment undefined behaviour has been invoked anything can happen, from seemingly working to crash of the program.

Comment: So basically to insert into array , array's dimension should be large enough to accomodate insertion of new values, then only it actually will signify insertion into array?

Comment: "*So basically to insert into array , array's dimension should be large enough to accomodate insertion of new values, *": Yes."*then only it actually will signify insertion into array?** I do not understand this doubts.

Comment: @v7676: Also I feel "*insertion*" is misleading. An array is defined to *have* N elements, to each of this N elements a value may be "*written*" or "*read*" from.